# SQL Server : inserting from different data type to another data type

Tags: sql-server

Ok, I have a table whose column type is date and I am inserting the value into that column like this

```
Concat(year(getdate()),'-','0',month(getdate()), '-', '01'),
```

it was working as expected, but now it throws this error

```
  Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

When I check, the convert function gives the output as varbinary, is there any other way to achieve this ?

I had already tried with convert or cast, I am getting the same issue

```
cast(Concat(year(getdate()),'-','0',month(getdate()), '-', '01') as date)
```

Comment: What convert function?   I don't see you using `convert` anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `'0'` from your query

Use like this

```
select cast(Concat(year(getdate()),'-',month(getdate()), '-', '01') as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting the first of the month, no need to turn it into a string which can cause errors.

```
select cast(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0) as date)
```

In your code, you will notice the output gives `2018-010-01` and this extra `0` will happen for the last three months.

To show how to do this with your method, you can just remove the 0.

```
select 
    cast(Concat( year(getdate()),
            '-',
            month(getdate()),
            '-', 
            '01') as date)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(getDate()), MONTH(getDate()) , 1)
```